# PowerMockito is not running in my code, here is my code

Tags: spring-boot, powermockito

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Topic_Service.class)
class Topic_Service_test
{  
  private Topic_Service topic_service =  PowerMockito.spy(new Topic_Service());

@Test
void testing_test() throws Exception
 {
   PowerMockito.doReturn("hello").when(topic_service, "test_help");
   String s = topic_service.testing();
   Assertions.assertEquals("hello testing",s);
 }
}


@Service
public class Topic_Service
{
  private String test_help()
  {
    return "test_help";
  }

 public String testing()
 {
   return test_help() + " " + "testing";
 }
}

 POM.XML Dependencies

    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version> 2.8.47</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

ERROR:-

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl (file:/home/an.kumar1/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-reflect/1.7.0/powermock-reflect-1.7.0.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize() WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected :hello testing Actual :null
```

can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using 1.7.4 version. With that above code runs successfully

Comment: I have changed my version also, but it is not working at all.

Comment: Please refrain from posting the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60846156/powermockito-is-not-able-to-mock-private-method) multiple times. Check my comment about the versions you are supposed to use.

Comment: I have changed my version but still not working at all.

Comment: Can you update the pom (and the error message) in your question with the new versions you are using? Also what java version are you using?